# How do I calculate the average interest rate for a dollar cost averaging investment?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I invested \$100 every month into the S&P 500 since January 2004. If I sold out on 2019-01-11 (not considering fees or dividends), I will have invested \$18,100 and my investment would be worth \$32,331.15.

How do I calculate my average yearly return (interest rate) on this investment?

---

**What I've tried so far**

My starting equation is 
$$
totalValue = monthlyAmount \cdot interest^{numYears} + monthlyAmount \cdot interest^{numYears - 1/12} + \dots + monthlyAmount \cdot interest^{1/12}
$$

I can then extract $monthlyAmount$ to simplify the expression:

$$
totalValue = monthlyAmount \cdot (interest^{numYears} + interest^{numYears - 1/12} + \dots + interest^{1/12})
$$

The part in the parentheses, if I'm not mistaken, seems to be the sum of a geometric sequence - where both the first term and the common ratio is $interest^{1/12}$. If so, then I can use the formula for calculating the sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric sequence:

$$
totalValue = monthlyAmount \cdot \frac{interest^{1/12} \cdot (1-interest^{1/12})}{1-interest^{numYears}}
$$

Alright, given the values in the introduction, I have an equation with a single unknown - the $interest$:

$$
32331.15 = 100 \cdot \frac{interest^{1/12} \cdot (1-interest^{1/12})}{1-interest^{15}}
$$

I gave this to WolframAlpha, and it gave me a [solution of 1.074 (i.e. 7.4%)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=32331%20%3D%20100%20*%20(x%5E(1%2F12)*(1-x%5E15)%2F(1-x%5E(1%2F12)))). That's nice, but how do I arrive at the solution?

**I'm writing a program that calculates this in the general case, so I'm ideally looking for some sort of algorithm that can be written in code.**

---

Source of financial information: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC/history?p=%5EGSPC

Comment: Hint:  write it out as a sum involving the rate and note that you have a geometric series.

Comment: @lulu No, because the stock price changes.

Comment: @Acccumulation  Why does that matter?  You are looking for a single rate $r$ which would match the return over the period.

Comment: I'ver misread the problem a couple of times now, so let me state how I am currently reading it.  I believe the OP is looking for the rate, $r$, such that a monthly investment of $100$ over $181$ periods would result in a total value of $32,331.15$  Thus, the first $100$ will have become $100\times (1+\frac r{12})^{181}$, the second will have grown to $100\times (1+\frac r{12})^{180}$ and so on.  Is this what was intended?

Comment: @lulu yes, that's what I meant. See my update for more information

Comment: Ok, and have I got the periods lined up correctly?  I have $181$ periods and the very last investment still gets one month's worth of interest.  Yes?

Comment: Note:  I originally recommended using Geometric Series but on reflection, I wouldn't bother.  Just implement the sum and use numerical methods.  Even crude methods converge very rapidly.  To be sure, even if you used Geometric Series, you'd need numerical methods to get a number.

Comment: I got $r=7.056\%$ based on the schedule of payments I described.

Comment: @lulu you're probably right. I made a mistake in my question, because I didn't consider the payment in the last month. Nevertheless, I'm not so much interested in the value for this particular example, but rather in a method to calculate it in the general case.

Comment: I think it's always best to proceed numerically from the start. I did it by a simple binary search .  I tried $r=5,6,7,8\%$ to get $7<r<8$. Then I tried $7.5$ to see that $7<r<7.5$ and so on. Found the answer very rapidly.  You could also implement a numerical version of Newton's method, but the crude binary search works very well.

Comment: @lulu huh, I didn't think of binary search, how simple! :) Thanks. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trusting that the schedule of payments I outlined in the comments are correct, the problem comes down to the following:  $$100\times \sum_{i=1}^{181}\left(1+\frac r{12}\right)^i=32,311.15$$

Now, it's possible to evaluate that sum as a rational function, but as that leads to a polynomial of degree $182$ in $r$ you'll be stuck with numerical methods anyway.  Instead, I'd leave the function as it stands and work numerically.  A simple binary search converges rapidly and we get $$r\approx 7.056\%$$

Answer (score 1):

Considering the general case, you want to solve for $x$ the equation
$$k=\frac TM=\sum_{i=1}^n(1+x)^i=\frac{(x+1) \left((x+1)^n-1\right)}{x}$$ where $T$ is the total value, $M$ the monthly amount, $n$ the number of months and $x$ the monthly interest.

As lulu explained, you need some numerical method (Newton method would be the easiest).

You can have good estimates of the solution considering that $x \ll 1$. So, let us expand the summation as a Taylor series (or use the binomial theorem) and get
$$k=n+\frac{n (n+1)}{2}  x+\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)}{6} n x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$

Neglecting the higher order terms, you just face a quadratic equation in $x$ anf then
$$x_0=\frac{\sqrt{24(n-1)n(n+1)k-3n^2(5 n^2-6 n-11) }-3n(n+1) } {2(n-1)n(n+1) }$$

For your example, this would give as an estimate $x=0.00626955$ corresponding to $7.52$%. Newton iterates would be

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.0062695483 \\
 1 & 0.0058852014 \\
 2 & 0.0058753116 \\
 3 & 0.0058753053
\end{array}
\right)$$ and then the answer $7.050366$%.

We could have a better estimate (still at the price of a quadratic equation in $x$) using, instead of Taylor series, a simple Padé approximant. This would give
$$k=\frac{n+\frac{1}{10} \left(n^2+13 n\right) x+\frac{1}{60} \left(n^3+3 n^2+20 n\right)
   x^2 } {1-\frac{2}{5} (n-2) x+\frac{1}{20} \left(n^2-3 n+2\right) x^2 }$$ Applied to the example, this would give as an estimate $x=0.00587785$ corresponding to $7.053$%.

**Edit**

We can even avoid solving quadratic equations building at $x=0$ the $[1,p]$ Padé approximant of
$$\frac{(x+1) \left((x+1)^n-1\right)}{x}-k=\frac{(k-n)+a_{(p)} x}{1+\sum_{j=1}^p b_j x^j}\implies x_{(p)}=\frac{n-k}{a_{(p)} }$$

For the simplest , the required coefficient is given by
$$a_{(1)}=\frac{1}{6} n (n+5)+\frac{1}{3} k (n-1)$$
$$a_{(2)}=\frac{3 n^2 (n+3)+2 (n-1) n (n+4)k+ (n-2) (n-1)k^2 } {2 n (n+5)+4  (n-1)k }$$ The formula becomes really long for $p \geq 3$ but they will be very easy to code.

Applied to the example, this would give
$$x_{(1)}\approx 0.00568499\implies 6.82198\text{ %}$$ 
$$x_{(2)}\approx 0.00585822\implies 7.02987\text{ %}$$
$$x_{(3)}\approx 0.00587585\implies 7.05102\text{ %}$$
$$x_{(4)}\approx 0.00587561\implies 7.05073\text{ %}$$
$$x_{(5)}\approx 0.00587532\implies 7.05039\text{ %}$$